# how to build and install pci_endpoint_test module

Tags: drivers, kernel, pcie

I'm new to linux.
I need to test PCIE port on Ubuntu, I can find pcie device by lspci command. But when I try to run pcitest.sh it shows can't find device. someone tell me to build and install pci_endpoint_test driver module on host machine. I'm confused with how to do it? I need some help